# Sharpening Grooves

Tags: golf, maintenance

Is there a DIY method to sharpening the grooves of your wedges? Up until now, my method has been to buy new wedges every other year. This gets expensive and frustrating. Especially with the new groove changes, I've wondered if its necessary.

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE! How often do you play in a given year (rounds + sessions on the driving range)?

Answer (score 1):

As far as physically sharpening grooves on a golf club, I would leave that to the professional.

Why? The high risk is not worth the little reward in terms of attempting to sharpen your own grooves. DIY may lead to buying new wedges anyway. Pro shops offer club services, and if you determine sharpening your grooves by a professional is relatively cost-effective than buying new wedges, this would be the route to go.

Assuming you play often, because replacing your wedges every other year is frequent on average, the best way to keep the grooves sharp is good maintenance. From a performance standpoint, it is beneficial to keep the wedge you have played with and gotten used to for a year or two *while* maintaining them as close to optimal condition as you can.

---

Good maintenance for golf clubs DIY is less risky. All you need is a bucket, dish detergent, a brush with **plastic** bristles (metal bristles can ruin the club), and a towel.

**These methods relate to irons. I do not recommend soaking metal/persimmon woods, hybrids, or putters.*

**Golf-course maintenance**

- After your shot, use a plastic tee to remove the dirt/debris from each groove of the
  club. Also, wipe off any remaining dirt/debris and dry with a towel.

  - Some players like to leave sand on their wedges after a bunker
    shot in order to create more spin (due to more friction) on their
    next shot with that wedge.
- If there are places on the course (or the back of your golf cart)
  where you can submerge and brush your golf clubs in soapy water, do so. Then, follow the initial step

**Full maintenance**

1. Fill the bucket with warm (not cool or too hot) water with a squirt of dish detergent.
2. Soak the clubs in the bucket for several minutes. Make sure anything above the hosel is not submerged.
3. Begin to clean each club thoroughly. Use your brush to rub along the grooves (parallel). Brushing too hard may ruin the coating of the club face.
4. Rinse your clubs thoroughly.
5. Dry your clubs with a towel and wipe the shaft in order to clean and dry them.